# Update and Delete from DataGridView not functioning

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` which displays 3 rows, when I try to update my records it says successfully changed the records. But when I check the database the records were not updated.

And in the delete button it says I must select a record to delete but I already selected a row in my `DataGridView`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace RFG_Inventory_and_Management_System
{
    public partial class AdminForm : Form
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RFG Inventory and Management System\RFG Inventory and Management System\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

        SqlCommandBuilder cmdbl;
        SqlDataAdapter adap;

        DataSet ds;
        int ID = 0;

        public AdminForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PayratesDisplay();
            NonMemberDisplay();
        }

        //Display Data in DataGridView  
        private void PayratesDisplay()
        {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_payrates", con);
            adap.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView4.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }
        private void NonMemberDisplay()
        {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT tbl_nonMember.*, tbl_customer.lname, tbl_customer.fname, tbl_customer.mname, tbl_customer.gender, tbl_customer.age, tbl_customer.membership_type FROM    tbl_nonMember INNER JOIN tbl_customer ON tbl_nonMember.customerID = tbl_customer.customerID", con);
            adap.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }

        //Clear Data  
        private void ClearData()
        {
            tbMemship.Text = "";
            tbPerses.Text = "";
            tbDisc.Text = "";
            ID = 0;
        }  

        private void AdminForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.tbl_customer' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tbl_customerTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.tbl_customer);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.tbl_nonMember' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tbl_nonMemberTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.tbl_nonMember);

        }

        private void fillByToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.tbl_customerTableAdapter.FillBy(this.database1DataSet.tbl_customer);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        //----------------------------------BUTTONS FOR PAY RATE-------------------------------------------------------------//

        //dataGridView1 RowHeaderMouseClick Event  
        private void dataGridView4_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            tbMemship.Text = dataGridView4.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            tbPerses.Text = dataGridView4.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            tbDisc.Text = dataGridView4.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        }  

        private void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tbMemship.Text != "" && tbPerses.Text != "" && tbDisc.Text != "")
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("update tbl_payrates set Membership=@Membership,PerSession=@PerSession where Discounted=@Discounted", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Membership", tbMemship.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerSession", tbPerses.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discounted", tbDisc.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
                con.Close();
                PayratesDisplay();
                ClearData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Update");
            } 
        }

        private void btn_PRadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to save Changes", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RFG Inventory and Management System\RFG Inventory and Management System\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_payrates (Membership, PerSession, Discounted) VALUES (@Membership, @PerSession, @Discounted)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Membership", tbMemship.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerSession", tbPerses.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discounted", tbDisc.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }   
        }

        private void btn_PRdel_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Update button update dataset after insertion,upadtion or deletion
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to save Changes", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                if (ID != 0)
                {
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tbl_payrates WHERE ID=@id", con);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted Successfully!");
                    PayratesDisplay();
                    ClearData();
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Delete");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try switching `con.Open();` before `cmd = new SqlCommand("` in all the function. and see if it helps. and I see that variable `ID` does not change anywhere thus it says `select a record to delete`

Comment: i tried to switch the `con.Open();` and `cmd = new SqlCommand` still the database is not updating. yes it says `select a record to delete`

Comment: Do you have a selected index change method for when the user selects the item they would like to delete? I suggest storing that value in a hidden field and setting that as the value you'd like to delete.

Answer (score 1):

The whole *AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `InventoryDb`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=InventoryDb;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are not assigned the value to id .so id always 0 and you are not able to delete the record. try to assign the value to ID and delete.i hope it will work without any problem.

```
private void btn_PRdel_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Update button update dataset after insertion,upadtion or deletion
        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to save Changes", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            if (ID != 0)// where is the id value?
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tbl_payrates WHERE ID=@id", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted Successfully!");
                PayratesDisplay();
                ClearData();
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Delete");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: but every time i try to delete a record and when I click the button the message `Please Select Record to Delete` is always showing even though I already selected a record in the `DataGridView`

Comment: please  show the  code , where you are assign the selected value to ID variable in delete method.